# Cannot resolve method java.util.List<S>

Tags: java, list, generics, interface, iterable

I've got following problem. I'd like to override superclass method with:

```
protected<S extends T> List<S> save(List<S> entities)
```

method signature. I'd like to add some processing and then call `super.save(entities)`
The problem is, that the external library has also `protected<S extends T> Iterable<S> save (Iterable<S> entities)` method. When I try to call super.save(entities) I'm facing `Cannot resolve method java.util.List<S>` error message. Do you have any clue how to sort it out?

EDIT:
Ok so we've got Interfaces like this:

```
public interface SomeInterface<T> {

  <S extends T> S save(S var1);
  <S extends T> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> entities);
}
```

then abstract class like this one:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T> implements SomeInterface<T> {
  @Override public <S extends T> S save(S var1) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override public <S extends T> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {
    return null;
  }
  public <S extends T> List<S> save(List<S> entities) {
    return null;
  }

  protected abstract void someAbstractMethod();
}
```

And I'd like to have my own implementation with some decoration methods (for this simple case it's an abstract method inside methods:

```
public class AbstractClassImpl<T> extends AbstractClass<T> {

  @Override public <S extends T> S save(S var1) {
    someAbstractMethod();
    return super.save(var1);
  }

  @Override public <S extends T> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {
    someAbstractMethod();
    return super.save(entities);
  }
  public <S extends T> List<S> save(List<S> entities) {
    someAbstractMethod();
    return super.save(entities); ...//error
  }


  @Override protected void someAbstractMethod() {

  }
}
```

The problem I mentioned occurs in `public <S extends T> List<S> save(List<S> entities)` this method.

Comment: I'd like to see the definitions for the super classes here.

Comment: Although IntelliJ marks the method call as read (which looks to be a bug), the code compiles fine here.

Comment: Yes you're right. I'm using intelliJ. I tried this code in eclipse and it compiles fine in fact. Thx